# Mutate vector according to list names

Tags: r, list, dplyr

Apologies if this has been asked elsewhere and I wasn't able to find it. I have a data frame with a character vector, say

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- data.frame(value = c('c','e','a','d'))
```

and a list, the names imperfectly correspond to the character vector `value` in `mydf`

```
    mylist <- list ('a' = '1',
                    'b' = '2',
                    'c' = '3',
                    'd' = '4')
```

**How can I define a new variable in `mydf` that takes on the elements of an item in the list if `value` equals the name of a given list item?**

In other words, the desired output is

```
mydf2 <- data.frame(value = c('c','e','a','d'),
                    value2 = c('3', 'e', '1', '4'))
```

I assume that this can be done with `case_when` and perhaps bang-bang notation but I can't quite square it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unlist` the `list` and use the named vector to `match` and replace the values in 'value' column and then with `coalesce` replace the non-matching i.e. `NA` to original column values

```
library(dplyr)
mydf3 <- mydf %>%
    mutate(value2 = coalesce(unlist(mylist)[value], value))
```

-output

```
mydf3
  value value2
1     c      3
2     e      e
3     a      1
4     d      4
```

---

Or another option is a join after converting the named `list` to a two column data.frame (`stack`) and then either use `coalesce` or `case_when/ifelse`

```
mydf %>% 
   left_join(stack(mylist), by = c("value"= "ind")) %>% 
   transmute(value, value2 =  case_when(is.na(values) ~ value, TRUE ~ values))
  value value2
1     c      3
2     e      e
3     a      1
4     d      4
```